# Can I use Android Studio when teammates uses Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Just a quick question I did not find a good answer on. We are currently working on an APP created with `Eclipse ADT Bundle`. I recently started exploring `Android Studio`, and like it. Is it possible to still collaborate with my mates using Eclipse with a shared GitHub repo?

I noticed Android Studio converts the project to its own file structure, so I guess this does not go well with Eclipse, and the repo.

Is there any solutions for this? So I can keep developing in Android Studio, push to GitHub, while the rest of the team use Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it, you'll just have to explicitly define a sourceSet that matches the Eclipse structure.  If you use any other build variants, they can't have any sourceSets because you wouldn't be able to check those files in to source control.  However, there are several useful things you can do with build variants just with the build file.  I think you can check in the build.gradle and other gradle stuff and it won't mess up your coworkers.